# Collapsing one list of dataframes and combining with another list of dataframes in R

Tags: r, list, dataframe, sorting

How can I handle processing two lists with multiple dataframes each in R? Example data:

```
set.seed(1)
set1 <- data.frame(NAME = paste("row_", 1:10, sep = ""),
                 SYMBOL = paste(c(sample(LETTERS, 10))),
                 SIGNIFICANT = sample(c("yes", "no"), 10, replace = TRUE))
set2 <- data.frame(NAME = paste("row_", 1:10, sep = ""),
               SYMBOL = paste(c(sample(LETTERS, 10))),
               SIGNIFICANT = sample(c("yes", "no"), 10, replace = TRUE))
set3 <- data.frame(NAME = paste("row_", 1:10, sep = ""),
                  SYMBOL = paste(c(sample(LETTERS, 10))),
                  SIGNIFICANT = sample(c("yes", "no"), 10, replace = TRUE))
set4 <- data.frame(NAME = paste("row_", 1:10, sep = ""),
                 SYMBOL = paste(c(sample(LETTERS, 10))),
                 SIGNIFICANT = sample(c("yes", "no"), 10, replace = TRUE))
files <- list(set1, set2, set3, set4)
names(files) <- paste("Set", 1:4, sep = "")
reports <- list(data.frame(SETS = c("Set1", "Set3"),
                        STATISTIC = runif(2)),
             data.frame(SETS = c("Set2", "Set4"),
                        STATISTIC = runif(2)))
names(reports) <- c("Report1", "Report2")
```

`files` is a list containing many dataframes of metadata from an analysis.

```
> files$Set1
     NAME SYMBOL SIGNIFICANT
1   row_1      Y          no
2   row_2      D          no
3   row_3      G          no
4   row_4      A         yes
5   row_5      B         yes
6   row_6      K         yes
7   row_7      N         yes
8   row_8      R         yes
9   row_9      W         yes
10 row_10      J         yes
```

`reports` is also a list containing 2 dataframes with primary outputs from a two-way analysis and associated statistics.

```
> reports$Report1
  SETS STATISTIC
1 Set1 0.4100841
2 Set3 0.8108702
```

Note that the names of the dataframes within the `files` list correspond with column 2 of the dataframes within the `reports` list.

I wish to collapse these `files` metadata in a particular way. If `files$Set1$SIGNIFICANT == 'yes'`, I would like to append the corresponding `SYMBOL` to a comma delimited string. Then, I would like to append the string to the corresponding Set within `reports`. Thus, my desired output would be as follows:

```
> head(reports$Report1)
  SETS STATISTIC              SYMBOL
1 Set1 0.4100841 A, V, K, N, R, W, J
2 Set3 0.8108702          F, S, J, V
```

and likewise for `Report2`

Easy enough to do manually for this example, but in my actual project, `length(files)=600`

I am attempting to parse this through a `for` loop but keep running into errors. Here is my current iteration

```
output <- data.frame()
for(i in 1:length(files)){
  for(j in 1:nrow(files[[i]])){
    if(files[j, 3] == "Yes"){
      output[i, 1]=i;
      output[i, 2]=paste0(i[,2], collapse = ", ")
    }
  }
}
```

And my current error:

```
Error in i[[j, 3]] : incorrect number of subscripts
```

I have been working with R for ~4 years now and if I know one thing, its that people avoid loops like the plague more often than not. I know some variation of `apply`, `lapply`, etc. is likely going to make life easy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `sapply` to iterate over `files` list from each dataframe keep only `SIGNIFICANT = 'yes'` values and collapse them into one string.

```
data <- stack(sapply(files,function(x) toString(x$SYMBOL[x$SIGNIFICANT=='yes'])))

data
#               values  ind
#1 A, B, K, N, R, W, J Set1
#2                B, F Set2
#3          F, S, J, V Set3
#4    W, Z, H, Q, D, M Set4
```

You can then `merge` `data` with each `dataframe` in `reports`.

```
result <- lapply(reports, function(x) merge(x,data, by.x = 'SETS', by.y = 'ind'))
result

#$Report1
#  SETS STATISTIC              values
#1 Set1 0.4100841 A, B, K, N, R, W, J
#2 Set3 0.8108702          F, S, J, V

#$Report2
#  SETS STATISTIC           values
#1 Set2 0.6049333             B, F
#2 Set4 0.6547239 W, Z, H, Q, D, M
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you can do this in two steps, first create a data.frame that has the significant symbols for each set. Here

```
sigset <- stack(lapply(files, function(x) paste(x$SYMBOL[x$SIGNIFICANT=="yes"], collapse=", ")))
names(sigset) <- c("SYMBOL","SETS")
```

We use `lapply()` to iterate the file list, extracting the significant symbols can combining them together, then we stack the list into a data.frame to make it easier to work with. We change the names so it can more easily merge on column name. Then we can merge this list with each of the reports

```
output <- lapply(reports, function(x) merge(x, sigset))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is solution similar to MrFlick's but using `subset`, `setNames`, and different `lapply` calls which may be slightly easier to read:

```r
# get the characters with SIGNIFICANT equal to "yes"
all_symbs <- lapply(files, subset, SIGNIFICANT == "yes", SYMBOL, TRUE)
# create one data.frame with the above after concatenating
all_files <- setNames(stack(lapply(all_symbs, paste0, collapse = ", ")),
                      c("SYMBOL","SETS"))
# merge with reports
res <- lapply(reports, merge, y = all_files)
# the result
res
#R> $Report1
#R>   SETS STATISTIC              SYMBOL
#R> 1 Set1 0.4100841 A, B, K, N, R, W, J
#R> 2 Set3 0.8108702          F, S, J, V
#R> 
#R> $Report2
#R>   SETS STATISTIC           SYMBOL
#R> 1 Set2 0.6049333             B, F
#R> 2 Set4 0.6547239 W, Z, H, Q, D, M
```

You can get rid of one of the `lapply` calls by creating an anonymous function instead of the two `lapply(files, ...)` and `lapply(all_symbs, ...)` calls.